# Creating spring forms in loop and submit all at once with Spring and JSp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form, multiple-forms

I am trying to create a survey like form in JSp using spring MVC. I have the backend architecture in place so are the data.

However, being fairly new to the technology, I am unable to figure out a fool-proof way of displaying the set of questions and submit answers for the question list.

Feature requirements :

**1. What would the model attribute for the spring form be if I am displaying all questions via c:forEach?**

**2. The user can save one answer at a time or save a set of answers at any point in time during the course of the survey. How do I handle this scenario?**

I am not looking for ready-made coding solutions. Any pointers/existing blogs/guides that references the above two questions would suffice.

Comment: Ready-mades coding is not avail.

Comment: Refer This Example :http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/

Comment: I came across this article and have implemented a solution on similar lines. I create a form that includes a map and the same has been sent to the jsp. However on submitting the form, the map is coming back empty. While in this example they seem to have come back from the form with actual data. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @SanjayPatel could you guide me?

Comment: Have you check given example?